# Converting image size from Maybe (Int, Int) to (Float, Float)

Tags: haskell, image

I have a function that returns size of an image `IO (Maybe (Int, Int))`
It would be nice to convert it to float tuple beautifully.

I am sure there must be a better way than what I currently have:

```
data Vec2D = Vec2D Float Float

getImageSize :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe (Int, Int))
getImageSize path = do
    img <- readImage path
    case img of
        Left _ -> return Nothing
        Right img' -> return (go img')
    where
        go :: DynamicImage -> Maybe (Int, Int)
        go (ImageRGB8 (Image w h _)) = Just (w, h)
        go (ImageRGBA8 (Image w h _)) = Just (w, h)
        go _ = Nothing

getImageSizeVec :: FilePath -> IO Vec2D
getImageSizeVec path = do
    res <- getImageSize path
    let dims = fromMaybe (0, 0) res
    return $ Vec2D (fromIntegral (fst dims)) (fromIntegral (snd dims))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I do not understand what benefit you get from the conversion to float
2. I would advise you to not mix - `IO` with the mostly pure calculation you have

so let us look at your code (minus the `IO`)

```
getImageSize :: DynamicImage -> Maybe (Int, Int)
getImageSize (ImageRGB8  (Image w h _)) = Just (w, h)
getImageSize (ImageRGBA8 (Image w h _)) = Just (w, h)
getImageSize _ = Nothing
```

but `readImage` already has a more useful return type than `Maybe` it has an `Either String` which is giving you error messages instead of `Nothing` so we can adjust.

```
getImageSize :: DynamicImage -> Either String (Int, Int)
getImageSize (ImageRGB8  (Image w h _)) = Right (w, h)
getImageSize (ImageRGBA8 (Image w h _)) = Right (w, h)
getImageSize _ = Left "Image type neither ImageRGB8 or ImageRGBA8"
```

this section could be improved a bit - also working on pure data

```
sizeToVec :: (Int,Int) -> Vec2D
sizeToVec (x,y) = Vec2D (fromIntegral x) (fromIntegral y)
```

you can then use those with the many mechanisms haskell provides you:

```
 readImage path :: IO (Either String DynamicImage)
 getImageSize :: DynamicImage -> Either String (Int, Int)
 sizeToVec :: (Int,Int) -> Vec2D
```

the last two you can combine à la

```
fmap sizeToVec (getImageSize img) -- or fmap sizeToVec . getImageSize
```

and the first two

```
doStuff = do eitherImg <- readImg mypathtoimg
             return $ do size <- getImageSize
                         sizeToVec size
```

or

```
doStuff = do eitherImg <- readImg mypathtoimg
             return (getImageSize eitherImg >>= sizeToVec)
```

or even shorter

<s>`doStuff = readImg mypathtoimg >>= (getImageSize >>= sizeToVec)`</s>

`doStuff = readImg path >>= fmap sizeToVec . getImageSize`

if I am not mistaken (I have no haskell env on this machine, therefore this code is untested - sorry)

Comment: `sizeToVec` has the wrong type for `>>=`. Perhaps you meant `readImg path >>= fmap sizeToVec . getImageSize`?